Make regular formatting fill show "on top" of Conditional Format fill?
I have a table in Excel that I have applied some conditional formatting to.
After creating the table, I've added a new column that I'm running a formula on.  Since this column isn't from the original dataset, I'd like my new column to be grey.
When I select my new column, and fill with grey, the grey is still "hidden" behind my Conditional Formatting fill color.
Is there a way to let my GREY color (or any 'regular fill') show on TOP of the Conditional Formatting?
Of course, I could adjust my CF range to exclude the new column, but that would require I break up the refers to range, and I'm hoping there's a non-VBA solution that allows me to keep my original CF rules/range.

The only way I can think of is to add an additional CF rule just on that new column that evaluates first AND stops so your original CF rules don't fire on that column.

@gns100 - Hm, not a bad idea. I added a rule (simply =TRUE) on that new column and filled grey, and it's working.  You can add that as an answer.  I'm hoping (but I have little faith) that there's a way in a setting somewhere, so I don't need to basically add to the CF rules (potentially slowing down the workbook).  But, I have a hunch your suggestion may be the easiest/quickest/best.  Thank you!

Converting my comment to an answer. My suggested solution to the ask was to create an additional conditional formatting rule (gray format) that would evaluate first then click the Stop If True so the original rule (green format) would not evaluate.

Note: in my testing the Stop If True did not do anything, but changing the order did. It probably something I missed in setting up the example answer.

Thanks to your post, I (hopefully) learnt it a bit more: Use conditional formatting to highlight information in Excel - Microsoft Support "For backwards compatibility, select the Stop If True check box in the Manage Rules dialog box to simulate how conditional formatting might appear in those earlier versions of Excel that do not support more than three conditional formatting rules or multiple rules applied to the same range. ..."
