How to color a specific number of cells in Excel, out of the cells that are not already colored by contitional coloring
I have a weekly schedule, and use conditional formatting to color a dynamic number of cells with the color red. I'm using the formula =ROW(A1)<=$B$10.
Now, I need to color a dynamic number of cells green, starting from the first cell that isn't red.
How can I do that?
Please see screenshot:

UPDATE:
I have found a solution. In a new row, I add the number of red cells to the number of green cells. That way, I ensure that the number of green cells that peak out is correct. Also, I move the green rule below the red rule. Now, only the green cells that peak below show, and that works well for me. Thank you, everybody!
Updated worksheet

Add in a new rule that fits your needs for the green cells, move it below the first rule, and check the box 'Stop if true' on your first rule.

Please post your data as text, not image.

Colour all the cell green, the conditional format will override the existing colour

For completeness, 'Stop if true' is not necessary for newer versions of excel... https://superuser.com/questions/1860319/make-regular-formatting-fill-show-on-top-of-conditional-format-fill/1860324#comment2951756_1860324

@Excellor
"Add in a new rule that fits your needs for the green cells, move it below the first rule, and check the box 'Stop if true' on your first rule. "
I tried to do that, but the green cells don't appear. I think they are behind, because if I try a higher number for the green cells, a few peak out below.

Consider editing your question to show us what you tried

I have found a solution. In a new row, I add to the number of green cells the number of the red cells, and move the green rule below the red rule. Now only the green cells that peak below show, and that works well for me. Thank you everybody!

@nerina You could answer your own question, so that other people with the same problem can look it up.

UPDATE:
I have found a solution. In a new row, I add the number of red cells to the number of green cells. That way, I ensure that the number of green cells that peak out is correct. Also, I move the green rule below the red rule. Now, only the green cells that peak below show, and that works well for me.
Updated worksheet:

